# Django Page not found Request Method: GET

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to figure out why my page can't be found. All the others previous ones are written exactly the same way. Why is this happening?

VIEWS:

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logg:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

URLS:

```
app_name = "learning_logg"
urlpatterns = [
    #Home Page
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('topics/', views.topics, name="topics"),
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topics, name="topics"),
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
]
```

NEW_ENTRY.HTML:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}


  

      <p>Add a new entry:</p>
        <form action="{% url 'learning_logg:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_pp }}
            <button name='submit'>Add entry</button>
        </form>
    
        <p><a> href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
    
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: when does it happen? when GETting or POSTing?

Comment: when POSTing hmmmm

Comment: from where you are getting id in your  `new_entry`

Comment: from topics.html

Comment: you have two urls called 'topics'

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in your new_entry.html.
Update your second last line to

```
<p><a> href="{% url 'learning_logg:topics' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
```

Instead of

```
<p><a> href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also change

```
return redirect('learning_logg:topic', topic_id=topic_id)
```

To

```
return redirect('learning_logg:topics', kwargs={'topic_id':topic.id})
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error?